# Default values for R Shiny selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

Here's a small example to illustrate my issue.  My real situation involves a dataframe with 14 columns and over 22 million rows...

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

model <- c("Prius", "Prius", "Prius", "Prius", "Civic", "Civic", "Civic", "Civic",
           "Civic Hybrid", "Civic Hybrid", "Civic Hybrid", "Escort", "Escort",
           "Escort", "Escort")
assembly <- c("Battery", "Battery", "CVT", "Brakes", "Engine", "Brakes", "Exhaust",
              "Transmission", "Battery", "Battery", "Brakes", "Engine", "Exhaust",
              "Brakes", "Lights")
part <- c("Cable", "Enclosure", "Paddle", "Paddle", "Cylinder", "Rotor", "Muffler",
          "Sensor", "Cable", "Emclosure", "Drum", "Piston", "Muffler", "Disc",
          "Bulb")
partNumber <- c(2290, 4755, 3152, 4111, 1754, 2827, 1602, 2622, 1305,
                4025, 4034, 1697, 3583, 4608, 1789)

CarDF <- data.frame(model, assembly, part, partNumber)



# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Minimal Example"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabPanel("Columns",
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                  choices = names(CarDF),
                                  selected = c("model", "assembly", "part", "partNumber")
               )
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = "model",
                  label = "Model", 
                  choices = unique(CarDF$model)
      ),
      
      selectInput(inputId = "assembly",
                  label = "Sub-assembly",
                  choices = unique(CarDF$assembly))
    ),
    
    # Show a table
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  selectedModel <- reactive({
    return(input$model)
  })
  
  
  # Chose a new model, update the list of available assemblies
  observeEvent(input$model, {
    assembly_choices <- CarDF %>% filter(model == selectedModel()) %>% select(assembly) %>% unique()
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "assembly", choices = assembly_choices)
  })
  
  
  #the dataframe to be displayed
  filtered_df <- reactive({ 
    tempFrame <- CarDF %>% filter(model == selectedModel()) %>% 
      filter(assembly == input$assembly) %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
    
    return(tempFrame)}
  )
  
  ########################################### the main data table
  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT(server=TRUE, {datatable(filtered_df(), extensions = 'Buttons',
                                                                   options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                                                                                  lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                                                                                  paging = TRUE,
                                                                                  searching = TRUE,
                                                                                  fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                                                                  autoWidth = TRUE,
                                                                                  ordering = TRUE,
                                                                                  #dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                                                  dom = 'tlip',
                                                                                  buttons = c('copy', 
                                                                                              'csv',
                                                                                              'excel')
                                                                   )
  )
  }
  )
  
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This runs and does everything I want for this small example.  But when I use this approach on my actual data, I get a warning from R

> Warning: The select input (the equivalent of Assembly in the above
> example) contains a large number of options; consider using
> server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the
> Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.

And so I modified the code

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

model <- c("Prius", "Prius", "Prius", "Prius", "Civic", "Civic", "Civic", "Civic",
           "Civic Hybrid", "Civic Hybrid", "Civic Hybrid", "Escort", "Escort",
           "Escort", "Escort")
assembly <- c("Battery", "Battery", "CVT", "Brakes", "Engine", "Brakes", "Exhaust",
              "Transmission", "Battery", "Battery", "Brakes", "Engine", "Exhaust",
              "Brakes", "Lights")
part <- c("Cable", "Enclosure", "Paddle", "Paddle", "Cylinder", "Rotor", "Muffler",
          "Sensor", "Cable", "Emclosure", "Drum", "Piston", "Muffler", "Disc",
          "Bulb")
partNumber <- c(2290, 4755, 3152, 4111, 1754, 2827, 1602, 2622, 1305,
                4025, 4034, 1697, 3583, 4608, 1789)

CarDF <- data.frame(model, assembly, part, partNumber)



# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Minimal Example"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tabPanel("Columns",
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                  choices = names(CarDF),
                                  selected = c("model", "assembly", "part", "partNumber")
               )
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = "model",
                  label = "Model", 
                  choices = unique(CarDF$model)
      ),
      
      #selectInput(inputId = "assembly",
      #            label = "Sub-assembly",
      #            choices = unique(CarDF$assembly))
       selectizeInput(inputId = "assembly",
                      label = "Sub-assembly",
                      choices = NULL),
    ),
    
    # Show a table
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  selectedModel <- reactive({
    return(input$model)
  })
  
  
  # Chose a new model, update the list of available assemblies
  observeEvent(input$model, {
    assembly_choices <- CarDF %>% filter(model == selectedModel()) %>% select(assembly) %>% unique()
    #updateSelectInput(inputId = "assembly", choices = assembly_choices)
    updateSelectizeInput(inputId = "assembly", choices = assembly_choices, server = TRUE)
  })
  
  
  #the dataframe to be displayed
  filtered_df <- reactive({ 
    tempFrame <- CarDF %>% filter(model == selectedModel()) %>% 
      filter(assembly == input$assembly) %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
    
    return(tempFrame)}
  )
  
  ########################################### the main data table
  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT(server=TRUE, {datatable(filtered_df(), extensions = 'Buttons',
                                                                   options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                                                                                  lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                                                                                  paging = TRUE,
                                                                                  searching = TRUE,
                                                                                  fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                                                                  autoWidth = TRUE,
                                                                                  ordering = TRUE,
                                                                                  #dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                                                  dom = 'tlip',
                                                                                  buttons = c('copy', 
                                                                                              'csv',
                                                                                              'excel')
                                                                   )
  )
  }
  )
  
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Basically just making these two changes:
In the UI

```
#selectInput(inputId = "assembly",
      #            label = "Sub-assembly",
      #            choices = unique(CarDF$assembly))
       selectizeInput(inputId = "assembly",
                      label = "Sub-assembly",
                      choices = NULL),
```

And in the server

```
observeEvent(input$model, {
    assembly_choices <- CarDF %>% filter(model == selectedModel()) %>% select(assembly) %>% unique()
    #updateSelectInput(inputId = "assembly", choices = assembly_choices)
    updateSelectizeInput(inputId = "assembly", choices = assembly_choices, server = TRUE)
  })
```

And this is where I get really confused.  In this example, the app runs but the `selectizeInput` for assembly is always blank.  In my larger app with the equivalent changes, it crashes at the equivalent of this line

```
tempFrame <- CarDF %>% filter(model == selectedModel()) %>% 
      filter(assembly == input$assembly) %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
```

With an error message that equates to

> Warning: Error in filter: ℹ In argument: `assembly == input$assembly`.
> Caused by error: ! `..1` must be of size 187999 or 1, not size 0.

I changed the names to match the example, the size numbers relate to my larger dataset.  The size 0 leads me to think there isn't a value yet for `input$assembly`?

I tried using the `selected` parameter in the `updateSelectizeInput` to just select the first option, but that didn't make a difference.

I'm not sure how to proceed at this point.  I feel like there's probably something very simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You need to update the selectize immediately. Per the [docs](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/selectize/), you can do this by itself (not in `observe`/`reactive`, dependent on nothing, fires once only). (This may not be strictly required in this one case, tbh, since you update it fairly quickly. I'm including this here in case there are server-size selectize questions where the choices are not instantly dynamically updated via another block.)
2. Your `observeEvent(input$model, ..)` is creating `assembly_choices` but it is a `data.frame` whereas `choices=` needs a vector. You can see this for yourself by adding `browser()` in that block and run your app. This is simple, just use `assembly_choices$assembly` or you can `pull()` it.

Add the first line and replace the appropriate `observeEvent` code with this:

```r
  updateSelectizeInput(inputId = "assembly", choices = unique(CarDF$assembly), server = TRUE)
  # Chose a new model, update the list of available assemblies
  observeEvent(input$model, {
    assembly_choices <- CarDF %>% filter(model == selectedModel()) %>% select(assembly) %>% unique() %>% pull(assembly)
    updateSelectizeInput(inputId = "assembly", choices = assembly_choices, server = TRUE)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed the issue in the example.  And (I'm ashamed to admit this) I found the error in my larger app was that I had mis-capitalized a variable name :(

Comment: Haha! Yes, I've done that second one too ... a clear case where code-highlighting (e.g., highlight a variable and see all other instances of that variable) can be very insightful. Glad it helped.

Comment: we use these things called work unit codes (WUCs) and it was the difference between `input$SearchKeyWUC` and `input$SearchKeyWuc`